# Kivy Image / Remove Image

Tags: python, kivy

Regarding a Kivy Image widget.  I can't seem to figure out how to remove the source to make it blank.

For example :

```
kivy_image_widget.source = None
```

I would like to clear the contents of an image widget when there is no data to display.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Have you tried `kivy_image_widget.reload()` after changing `source` to `None`?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Since *source* is a StringProperty, assign an empty string to it.

```
kivy_image_widget.source = ''
```

[Image »source](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.source)

> ```
> source
> ```
>
> Filename / source of your image.
>
> source is a StringProperty and defaults to None.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def clear_image(self):
        self.ids.img2.source = ''
        self.ids.img2.reload()


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Image:
        id: img1
        source: 'kivyLogo.png'

    Image:
        id: img2
        source: 'raspberrypi.png'

    Button:
        text: 'Clear Image 2'
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        on_release:
            root.clear_image()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02 - Image 2 Cleared]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make it blank, use `opacity` property like this:

```
kivy_image_widget.opacity = 0
```